# Firefox could not initialize application security crash

Tags: firefox

Hi there I installed Ubuntu a few minutes ago (i'm very new on Ubuntu) and whenever I want to open Firefox I get an error which starts with "could not initialize application security ...".

Also when I try to restart Ubuntu it stops and I have to shut-down manually with the power button. During the shutdown there is a message

> Killing all remaining processes --> fail

I will be glad if you can help me and thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have a corrupted Firefox profile to deal with this problem you will need to run Firefox profile manager to do this open a terminal open the dash and type terminal
and enter this command at the prompt `firefox -profilemanager` like this

[image: Terminal showing firefox -profilemanager command]

and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key

you should then see a dialogue like this

[image: Firefox profile manager]

you need to first delete the default profile then create a new profile

Hope this helps

Comment: well i to installed ubuntu 11.10 again and there is no any problem rigth now so everything looks ok now. anyway thanks for help mate.

Comment: before you go about deleting your current profile you can try creating a new profile to see if that works. Otherwise you've deleted your current profile for nothing

Answer (score 1):

This  error message can be from one of 3 problems:

1) You are **out of hard drive space**.

2) **Incorrect permissions** in your mozilla / firefox directory `~/.mozilla`

3) A **corrupt database**, `cert8.db`

So while many people advise you simply delete your firefox profile, that does not really address the problems and you will loose your customizations (bookmarks).

So, first , check to make sure your home or root partitions are not full. If they are, make more space.

Second, make sure your permissions are correct (this will fix any permissions problem in your home directory, firefox or otherwise).

```
sudo chown -R your_user:your_user /home/your_user
```

Last, if that fails, delete cert8.db

```
rm -f ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/cert8.db
```

For details see http://kb.mozillazine.org/Could_not_initialize_the_browser_security_component

One of those 3 steps should fix the issue without deleting your customizations.

Comment: well i to installed ubuntu 11.10 again and there is no any problem rigth now so everything looks ok now. anyway thanks for help mate.

Comment: There's a more recent link now https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/couldnt-initialize-applications-security-component

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.mozilla
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox and its profile does a little bit more than most people think i found out today if you care to look.

The android version of Firefox without any plugins is listening in to DLNA broacast messages from devices like XBoxes and Samsung Smart TVs and then making a UPNP request to the devices to recive XML data back from these devices.

In my case this not only includes the make and model of the TV but also the serial number and its not like my simple android device can stream to the TV or play XBox games.

Shown below is both the request and reply I captured with some of the data replaced using XXX and I also had to tweak the HTML tags in the XML so it would post.

```
GET /smp_24_ hxxp/1.1
Host: X.X.X.40:7676
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Tablet; rv:36.0) Gecko/36.0 Firefox/36.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive

hxxp/1.1 200 OK
CONTENT-LANGUAGE: UTF-8
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
CONTENT-LENGTH: 1167
Date: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 03:59:18 GMT
connection: close
Application-URL: hxxp://X.XX.40:80/ws/app/
SERVER: SHP, UPnP/1.0, Samsung UPnP SDK/1.0

[?xml version="1.0"?][root xmlns='urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0' xmlns:sec='hxxp://www.sec.co.kr/dlna' xmlns:dlna='urn:schemas-dlna-org:device-1-0'] [specVersion]  [major]1[/major]  [minor]0[/minor] [/specVersion] [device]  [deviceType]urn:dial-multiscreen-org:device:dialreceiver:1[/deviceType]  [friendlyName][TV]Samsung50[/friendlyName]  [manufacturer]Samsung Electronics[/manufacturer]  [manufacturerURL]hxxp://www.samsung.com/sec[/manufacturerURL]  [modelDescription]Samsung TV NS[/modelDescription]  [modelName]XXX9200[/modelName]  [modelNumber]1.0[/modelNumber]  [modelURL]hxxp://www.samsung.com/sec[/modelURL]  [serialNumber]XXXXXXXXXX[/serialNumber]  [UDN]uuid:0dbXXXXXXXXXXXX[/UDN]  [sec:deviceID]XXXXXXOMKVUK[/sec:deviceID]  [sec:ProductCap]Resolution:1280X720,Y2013[/sec:ProductCap]  [serviceList]   [service]    [serviceType]urn:dial-multiscreen-org:service:dial:1[/serviceType]    [serviceId]urn:dial-multiscreen-org:serviceId:dial[/serviceId]    [controlURL]/smp_26_[/controlURL]    [eventSubURL]/smp_27_[/eventSubURL]    [SCPDURL]/smp_25_[/SCPDURL]   [/service]  [/serviceList] [/device][/root]
```

Comment: Perhaps you might explain a little more as to how this helps answer the question.